# How to prevent logging object been overwritten

Tags: python, logging

I'm using a 3rd party lib, but seems the lib imports logging and modifies the configs (`logging.basicConfig, logging.dictConfig, etc`) that messed up my console and file logging, I'm looking for a way to prevent my logging been modified.

I've tried copy the logging object and reassign it back once it's done, but `copy.deepcopy` wont allow me to clone the original object - saying it `cant can't pickle _cffi_backend.CTypeDescr objects`:

```
    logging_obj = copy.deepcopy(logging)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 334, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
TypeError: can't pickle _cffi_backend.CTypeDescr objects
```

so I tried to inspect its contents (but only converted to str and compared), and I found `_handlerList` was the one been modified, but still wont work after I reassign it back:

```
handler_list = copy.deepcopy(logging.__dict__['_handlerList'])
obj = {}
for k in logging.__dict__:
    obj[k] = str(logging.__dict__[k])
# some 3rd party lib calls
self.logger.info("containers: {}".format(containers))
logging.__dict__['_handlerList'] = handler_list
# print out different obj, will print nothing after assign handler_list back (above line)
for k in logging.__dict__:
    if not str(logging.__dict__[k]) == obj[k]:
        print k
        print "=="*100
        print logging.__dict__[k]
        print "--"*50
        print obj[k]
        print "=="*100
```

Hope someone could help me out, I dont even know if I'm doing this right (probably not...but I don't know how and couldn't find how), the 3rd party lib was actually built for cli usages, but I'm trying to import and treat it as a lib.

And I always have a hard time understanding python's logging, it'll be really great if anyone could also suggest some logging articles.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, it turns out to be my logger was mysteriously disabled, before the 3rd lib call, my `logger.__dict__`:

```
{
    'name': 'log/controller.log',
    'parent': < logging.RootLogger object at 0x10cb3d190 > ,
    'handlers': [ < logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler object at 0x10de5d4d0 > , < logging.StreamHandler object at 0x10de5da90 > ],
    'level': 20,
    'custom': < function custom at 0x10de6a668 > ,
    'disabled': 0,
    'manager': < logging.Manager object at 0x10cb3d250 > ,
    'propagate': False,
    'result': < function result at 0x10de6a6e0 > ,
    'filters': []
}
```

after the call, **disabled** became **True**:

```
{
    'name': 'log/controller.log',
    'parent': < logging.RootLogger object at 0x10cb3d190 > ,
    'handlers': [ < logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler object at 0x10de5d4d0 > , < logging.StreamHandler object at 0x10de5da90 > ],
    'level': 20,
    'custom': < function custom at 0x10de6a668 > ,
    'disabled': True,
    'manager': < logging.Manager object at 0x10cb3d250 > ,
    'propagate': False,
    'result': < function result at 0x10de6a6e0 > ,
    'filters': []
}
```

after setting it back (`logger.disabled = 0`), my logger started to print and log to files again.

Hope this helps someone encounters the same issue.